# How debug the issue of Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee1ba8578)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, github-mantle

I encounter the Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee1ba8578) error.

As I know this cause from abnormal object release.

But seem as stuck `[MTLModel description]` infinite loop.

[image]

Even already add one exception breakpoint in project and enable Zombie Objects in Edit Scheme, the console still without any information and output when error occurs.

Is there any idea or experience for debugging.

Comment: Sometimes all relevant information is displayed after pressing the *Continue* button in the debug area.

Comment: Still stuck same point and without output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you by any chance have a property in your model named `description` ?  If so, please note that `description` is reserved in Objective-C to generate a NSString description of an object.  You will probably need to name it "desc" or some other name and use the `JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey` to associate the "description" property of your JSON model to your "desc" property of your Objective-C model.

Comment: The `description` method was use by [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) self, I'm not overriding `description` method. And have not property call the description.
However I return one common NSString could solve this infinite loop symptom.
Maybe cause from the dictionary object of permanentProperties in loop.
Reference from [Mantle issue](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle/issues/88)